# Android Screen Press Detection

Tags: android, touch

I am trying to build an app that detects if a user puts their lips on the screen. How could I get an image of their lips when they put it on the screen?

Is there possibly a way to get a grid of the screen and then determine where they were placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-touch support depends on the version of Android.  You need at least 2.0.  I understand that Android in principle supports up to 256 "fingers" at once, but I'm currently playing with it and my HTC Desire supports 2 fingers.  I don't think what you're after will be possible on many devices, if any.

Comment: Well let's say that I have a 2.0 device that supports up to 256 in principle, then what?

Comment: Then there's no reason I can think of why you couldn't just capture which parts of the screen various parts of their lips are touching. There is also, I believe, the ability to take pressure readings on the touched parts of the screen but I've not looked into that because it's not relevant to my current Android project.   I'll be honest - it's not something I've ever really thought about!